# How to get both colliding sprite objects in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

If a collision occurs, is there a way to get both objects?

For example:

```
allSprite = pygame.sprite.Group()
Bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()
Enemies = pygame.sprite.Group()

bullet = Bullet()
enemy = Enemy()
Bullets.add(bullet)
Enemies.add(enemy)

hits = pygame.sprite.collide(Enemies,Bullets)
for hit in hits:
    hit.damage()
```

This only gets the `Enemy` object, but I want both objects because I need the bullet damage, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `groupcollide` function for this:
http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.groupcollide

You will get back a dictionary of Enemies (keys) and for each Enemy, a list of the Bullets that hit it (values).  Then you can do something like this:

```
hits = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(Enemies, Bullets, False, True)
for enemy in hits:
    for bullet in hits[enemy]:
        enemy.damage(bullet.damage)
```

Comment: Thatnks a lot bro.